# Prove that $f(s) = \sup\{x \in [a,b] : f(x) > x\}$, where $f$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Given $f: [a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ increasing, where $f(a) > a$ and $A = \{x \in [a,b] : f(x) > x\}. \ $ If $s = \sup(A), $ prove that $f(s) = s$.

In order to show that $f(s) = s$, I was trying to prove that $f(s) \leq s$ and $f(s) \geq s$.

Can I simply state that since $f$ is an increasing function then $f(s) \geq s$?  How can I prove that $f(s) \leq s$?

Comment: "Can I simply state..." Not obviously. Increasing does not mean $f(x)\geq x,$ it means $f(t)\geq f(s)$ when $t\geq s.$ $f(x)=x^2$ is increasing on $[0,1].$

Comment: I know that $\forall x \in A, s \geq x$, which means $f(s) \geq f(x) > x$. Does this imply $f(s) \geq s$?

Comment: That argument is fine, but it doesn't qualify as "simply stating" it. You had to make the argument. $f(s)\geq f(x)> x$ for all $x\in A$ means $f(s)\geq \sup A=s,$ yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've shown $f(s)\geq s.$

To summarize, since it is in comments only:

> For $x\in A,$ $s\geq x$ and thus $f(s)\geq f(x)>x,$ so $f(s)\geq \sup A=s.$

If $f(s)>s,$ then in particular, $s<b,$ since $f(b)\leq b.$ Let $\delta=\frac{f(s)-s}2>0.$ Then, since $f(s)\leq b,$ we have $$s+\delta\leq s+\frac{b-s}2=\frac{s+b}2<b.$$
So
$$f(s+\delta)\geq f(s)=s+(f(s)-s)> s+\delta,$$ which means $s+\delta\in A,$ contradicting $s=\sup A.$

---

Essentially, we are proving that for each $x\in A,$ there is an $x'>x$ with $x'\in A,$ so the supremum cannot be in $A.$

Comment: Thanks for your help! The only part I don't get is why $f(s+\delta) > s+\delta$ implies that $s+\delta  \in A$. How do we know that $s + \delta \in [a,b]$?

Comment: Okay, edited to ensure $s+\delta\leq b.$ @Matias

Comment: Basically, $f(s)+\delta\leq \frac{b+s}2<b,$ since $s\neq b.$